# Why EXC_BAD_ACCESS happen only with LLVM library but not with GNU library?

Tags: c++, exc-bad-access

Few days ago, I have found out the oracle instant client is not compatible with LLVM C++ library due to EXC_BAD_ACCESS. Therefore, I change the library to GNU C++ library and every thing works.

Today, I realized the error from oracle client may be caused by returning a local variable. When the program is compiled with LLVM C++ library, EXC_BAD_ACCESS comes out. However, I change the library to GNU C++ library, the vector can push 10 but it cannot get back the 10. I have no idea why EXC_BAD_ACCESS only occurs with LLVM library.

LLVM (local)
[image]

GNU(local)
[image]

Comment: Images of code is not useful, please replace with a text version of the code.

Comment: It's not a compatibility problem - your code is broken. Undefined behaviour means that anything can happen. In this case, it means that it crashes in one case and doesn't in the other.

Comment: See the yellow warning on line 17? That's your problem. Try reading and understanding it.

Comment: I know the code is broken and I know what is the meaning of EXC_BAD_ACCESS. I just want to understand the reason of the different behavior between the 2 libraries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are invoking undefined behaviour.

Exactly what happens on any given execution of your program is not defined and can vary from compiler to compiler. That is clearly what is happening here. You just got unlucky that that your broken code ran without error with the GNU library.